# Recording Java stdout and stderr

Tags: java, stdout, bukkit

What I would like to do is **record** not redirect java `System.out` and `System.err`. I want to be able to save everything that is printed out, while still having it actually print to the console/default destination. I can't change the runtime. I need it to do this in the Java process, seeing as it will be in a Bukkit plugin. Thanks!

Comment: I plan to send it through a PrintStream (after some editing) to a Socket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the original values of `System.out` and `System.err`, extend `PrintStream` to create a class that records the output and forwards it to another `PrintStream`.

Then you can just do

```
System.setOut(new RecordingStream(System.out));
System.setErr(new RecordingStream(System.err));
```

Comment: I thought of that, I was just wondering if there was a better way. Oh well, guess not

Comment: The fact that they are `PrintStreams` limits the options somewhat. This is the most straight forward way, and it's not a *bad* way.